# generate entity classes from database in play framework 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am newbie to play framework 2.0.3, trying to generate entity classes for a database tables. I read play 2.0 documentation, they are mentioning about Ebean to create entity classes. I didn't get it. And I looked into this tutorial as well . https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaEbean

Any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you have existing DB structure and you'd like to generate models for them?

Unfortunately, this works exactly in the second direction: you need to create these classes, then if you have enabled auto update, Ebean will create new DDL based on these classes as a new evolution, and then will ask you to confirm evolution's applying at next page refresh.

Of course you don't need to perform evolutions if there are no changes to DB and you need only add required classes.

Put them in the `/app/models` package, take a look at the doc (you pointed) and also Java samples how it behaves, ie: `app/models/SomeModel.java` will create `some_model` table (if you won't override it with annotation)

And... be careful, **Ebean plugin with auto-generated evolution destroys whole DB** and rebuilds it from the scratch so it's dangerous to use it in the production, in such case you have to switch to manual-written evolutions.